# Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

[image]

I try to do the configuration again but i coudl not do it

[image]

Now I see my Services Stopped bu I can't start again because in Action is not possible

I'm trying to open a page but I'm getting the next error:

> An unexpected error has occurred.   Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.   Correlation ID:
>   8005fa8b-6fc9-4a11-9ecb-9e8fba160035  Date and Time: 11/6/2013
>   12:07:01 PM

I couldn't open any page and I really don't know why. I can only open SharePoint 2010 Central Administration, that is all. I confirmed the event viewer and I only find the next message but I don't know if this is the root cause of the trouble.

> "There are no instances of the User Profile Service started on any
>   server in this farm. Ensure that at least one instance is started on
>   an application server in the farm using the Services on Server page in
>   Central Administration."

*Edit*:

Central Administration : Services on Server: SERVER

The Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database Status = Started

[EXTRA COMMENT]
I don’t know the root cause of the trouble I only did a copy of the server (Virtual Server) but I don´t know if this action generated the problem and the lost setting

Comment: I try to access to Manage Profile Service: User Profile Service Application but I could not access

Comment: What do the [ULS logs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2009/12/22/uls-viewer-for-sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting.aspx) say about the correlation ID?

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration, goto Services on Server.  Ensure that the User Profile Service is started on your server.

Comment: Hello I review that

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database Status = Started

Comment: Central Administration : Services on Server: SERVER and the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database Status = Started

Comment: Are you checking for the "User Profile Service" on the Services on Server page?

Comment: I reviewed System Settings\Manage services on server and I found that all services are Stopped Like SharePoint Foundation Search, SharePoint Server Search, User Profile Service, User Profile Synchronization Service, etc. but I don't know why

Comment: Sorry I forgot and in Action section I can't see any things to start the service What I need to do? how to start the service

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes sure I already upload the image

Comment: From the start menu, right click the Central Administration link and run as administrator. You should see the links then.

Comment: Hello John C. First Thanks for your suppor I did that but the same I can't start the service I realy don't know why